# define border width(not thickness)

Tags: javascript, css, border

can I define border width. like

```
.box{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

box width is `200px` but i want border width in bottom only `100px`.

[image]

Comment: can you put up a sketch of what you're trying to do?

Comment: that's not a border, that's a line independent from the element. you can even use <hr /> for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want half a border. Strange, but doable, I think. This is working in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. MSIE I don't have on hand at the moment, and may cause problems.

The way this works is to have an enclosing box with a background-color that's half as wide, and 1 pixel taller than `div.box`. I put a background of gray on the body so you can see it working.

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #000;
}
.box-border {
    width: 100px; /* half as wide as .box! */
    height: 101px; /* just slightly taller than .box! */
    background-color: #000;
    overflow: visible; /* .box, inside this, can go outside it */
}
.box{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="box-border">
        <div class="box">
            The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

No. You'll have to put another element within the `.box`, which is 100px wide, and apply the border to that.

Answer (score 0):

or you define a background image like that:
.box {
    background:url(border.gif) no-repeat 0 bottom;}

and the image is 100px wide and for example 2px heigh.